# Train a cforest in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest, party

I have a very large data frame with 790,000 rows and 140 predictors. Some of these are strongly correlated to each other, and on different scales. With the `randomForest` package, I can grow a forest on each core using only a small sample of the data, using `foreach` and merge them with the `combine()` function to get one big tree, like so:

```
rf.STR = foreach(ntree=rep(125, 8), .combine=combine, .multicombine=TRUE, .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
  sample.idx = sample.int( nrow(dat), size=sample.size, replace=TRUE)
  randomForest(x=dat[sample.idx,-1, with=FALSE], 
               y=dat[sample.idx, retention], ntree=ntree)
  }
```

The correlated variables on different scales leads me to want to use conditional random forests from the `party` package, but there's no `combine()` method for cforests, so I'm not sure how to combine several cforest objects to get one importance plot or one prediction.

Is there a way to train one big cforest on smaller subsets of the data, or make several small cforests and combine them into one bigger conditional forest model?

Comment: Try the `h2o` package that can be downloaded [here](http://www.h2o.ai). Very fast, open source and runs in parallel. The update so fast that their documentation lacks a bit in consistency sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! From reading the RF documentation, it doesn't seem like it has conditional trees. Since some of my predictors are strongly correlated, if I run the usual RF, the variable importance will put a bunch of highly predictive but correlated variables at the top, which is less useful than if it only selected one of them.

Comment: The implementation `party::cforest` does not support parallelization (as far as I know). In the (slower) reimplementation `partykit::cforest` we have added support for parallelization but at the moment the `partykit` version does not yet provide all features of the old `party` implementation. Specifically, no variable importance measures are implemented at the moment. Thus, this will not be of much use to you. You could contact the `party` maintainer (Torsten Hothorn) directly whether he has a recommendation how to split up the learning of `party::cforest`.

Comment: Thanks, Achim. That's probably the best I'm going to do on the subject. If you would submit that as a full answer, I'll accept it, until such time as partykit gets an importance() function :).

Comment: It's really so unsatisfactory as an answer that a comment is embarrassing enough :-)

Comment: Hah! Alright, fair enough. Seems like the state of conditional random forests are somewhat undeveloped, compared to other random forest variations. Oh well.

Comment: @ChristopherAden, did you ever solve this problem? Running into the same issue now

Answer (score 0):

make several small cforests and combine them into one bigger conditional forest model.

```
library(snowfall)
library(party)
cforestmt<-function(formula, data = list(), subset = NULL, weights = NULL, controls = cforest_unbiased(), xtrafo = ptrafo, ytrafo = ptrafo, scores = NULL, threads=8) {

    if(controls@ntree<threads) {    # if there are less trees than threads single thread
        return(cforest(formula, data = data, subset=subset, weights=weights, controls=controls, xtrafo=xtrafo, ytrafo=ytrafo, scores=scores))
    }

    # round off threads
    fsize=controls@ntree/threads
    if(fsize-round(fsize)!=0) {
            fsize=ceiling(fsize)
            message("Rounding forest size to ",fsize*threads)
    }
    controls@ntree=as.integer(fsize)

    # run forests in parallel
    sfInit(parallel=T, cpus=threads, type="SOCK")
    sfClusterEval(library(party))
    sfExport('formula','data','subset','weights','controls','xtrafo','ytrafo','scores')
    fr<-sfClusterEval(cforest(formula, data = data, subset=subset, weights=weights, controls=controls, xtrafo=xtrafo, ytrafo=ytrafo, scores=scores))
    sfStop()

    # combine/append forest
    fr[[1]]@ensemble<-unlist(lapply(fr,function(y) {y@ensemble}),recursive=F)
    fr[[1]]@where<-unlist(lapply(fr,function(y) {y@where}),recursive=F)
    fr[[1]]@weights<-unlist(lapply(fr,function(y) {y@weights}),recursive=F)

    #first forest has result
    return(fr[[1]])
}
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.